# Curvature multiplied by constant?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors, curvature

I.e: the vector function $\{t^3, t^2, t\}$ has a curvature of $\dfrac17\sqrt{\dfrac{19}{14}}$, but what happens when you multiply the curvature to something like $3\{t^3, t^2, t\}$? I figure you can just recalculate the curvature at large, but am wondering if this just multiplied the overall curvature by $3$. 
Thanks!

Comment: Bump This? Please??

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Imagine that you scale a circle by a factor of $3$. What happens to the radius? Now use the fact that $\kappa=\frac1r$.